# Cannot center a row

Tags: html, css, sass, haml

[image]I have 4 columns in a row and I cannot get the row centered.  It's so weird... 
If you look at the pic at the bottom, you can see the row is not centered by looking at the vertical border under the "most read" blue square. 
html file:

```
<div class="block-section">
  <div class="sm-section-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="sm-preview-title">
        MOST READ  
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="sm-preview-wrapper">
          <h3 class="preview-sm">
            hello world
          </h3>
          <h2 class="preview-sm">
            Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="sm-preview-wrapper">
          <h3 class="preview-sm">
            hello world
          </h3>
          <h2 class="preview-sm">
            Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="sm-preview-wrapper">
          <h3 class="preview-sm">
            hello world
          </h3>
          <h2 class="preview-sm">
            Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="sm-preview-wrapper">
          <h3 class="preview-sm">
            hello world
          </h3>
          <h2 class="preview-sm">
            Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my scss file:

```
.sm-preview-wrapper{
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid $light-gray;
  padding: 0 35px;
}

.sm-section-wrapper{
  @include clearfix();
  .col-3{
    margin: 0;
    &:last-child{
      .sm-preview-wrapper{
        border-right: none;
      }
    }
  }
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 36px;
  .sm-preview-title{
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    width: 165px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: $blue;
    font-family: $montserrat;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS or HAML->HTML compilation problem, only post the compiled CSS/HTML.  This is not a Sass *or* HAML problem.

Comment: @cimmanon Sorry, I don't understand.  Are you having trouble reading the HAML and Sass?

Comment: It is unreasonable to expect CSS experts (you know, the people who would actually be able to help you) to install a Sass and HAML compiler just so that they can answer your question especially when you could have taken the 2 seconds to get the compiled output.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9v98r58s/

You are using the border for .sm-preview-wrapper and not its parent .col-sm-3 which has a padding of 15px.

A solution is to use :after for the border

```
.sm-preview-wrapper:after{
            position:absolute;
            right:-15px;
            width:1px;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
            content:'';
            background:red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a percentage margin to the first and last child to take up the entire width and center it.